# How to detect touch event that doesn't move but holding a finger on the screen

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to make some rhythm games with android and want to implement slide notes.
I want to detect touch event that finger stays on the screen but it doesn't move.
However, MotionEvent detects only Action_down, Action_move and Action_up.
How can I solve this problem? I tried to use thread but it's cost is too big for multi-touch event.

Thank you for all you guys to read this questions.

Comment: As far as I know, The only way to achieve **Continuous Touch Event** is to create a thread, But If you don't want that, Then try adding below line of code and let me know, Thanks
`view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);`